# Integral of fractional Laplacian is zero

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is it true that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(-\Delta)^su(x) dx = 0,$$
where $(-\Delta)^s$ is the [fractional Laplacian](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian)?

Comment: Seems clear from the Fourier-transform definition of $(-\Delta)^s$:
the integral over ${\bf R}^n$ of $(-\Delta)^s u$
is the value at zero of the Fourier transform of $(-\Delta)^s u$;
but this Fourier transform is $\xi \mapsto |\xi|^{2s} \, \widehat u(\xi)$,
so it vanishes at $\xi = 0$, **QED**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under certain assumptions. 
For $0<\alpha<2$ and $\varphi\in\mathscr{S}_n$ we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}\varphi 
& = &
\frac{1}{2\gamma(-\alpha)}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}
\frac{\varphi(x+y)+\varphi(x-y)-2\varphi(x)}{|y|^{n+\alpha}}\, dy,
\end{eqnarray*}
where
$$
\gamma(-\alpha)=
\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}2^{-\alpha}\Gamma\left(-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+\alpha}{2}\right)}\,.
$$
One can show that
$$
(x,y)\mapsto\frac{\varphi(x+y)+\varphi(x-y)-2\varphi(x)}{|y|^{n+\alpha}}\in L^1(\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n).
$$
Then integrating $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}\varphi$ over $\mathbb R^n$ and applying Fubini theorem yields zero. The same applies to $s=\frac{\alpha}{2}+k$, where $k$ is a positive integer since
\begin{eqnarray*}
(-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}+k}\varphi 
& = &
\frac{(-1)^k}{2\gamma(-\alpha)}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}
\frac{\Delta^k\varphi(x+y)+\Delta^k\varphi(x-y)-2\Delta^k\varphi(x)}{|y|^{n+\alpha}}\, dy.
\end{eqnarray*}
You can find proofs for example

[here](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Harmonic%20Analysis4.pdf) (Theorem 7.13 and Corollary 7.16). The argument does not apply to negative powers of the Laplacian. The negative powers of compactly supported smooth functions are rarely integrable (I think).

Comment: OK. My answer is correct, but overly complicated (see comment by Noam D. Elkies). However, some people use the integral fromula from my solution as a definition of the fractional Laplacian.

Comment: Does the result hold for $\varphi \in W^{2,\infty}$?

Comment: @Dal: The explicit example in my answer is a counter-example (unless $n = 1$ and $\alpha \geqslant 1$; then $f'$ is a counter-example). You do need some kind of integrability of $\varphi$ at infinity.

Comment: @Dal: A simplest example $n=1$, $s=1$, $u(x)=\sin x$, $-\Delta u = -u''=u$ is not integrable.

Comment: Thanks. Then what is the lightest assumption on $\varphi$ that makes the result true?

Answer (score 6):

Noam D. Elkies and Piotr Hajlasz give a positive answer to the original question, with two different proofs. While their arguments are completely fine, they are somewhat restrictive: the integral of $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f$ is zero if $f$ is integrable (and regular enough). The general answer is **no**!

---

Suppose that $\alpha < n$, and let $g$ be any continuous, compactly supported (or merely integrable) function. Let
$$ f(x) = c_{n,\alpha} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{g(y)}{|x - y|^{n - \alpha}} \, dy $$
be the Riesz potential of $g$. Then $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (for the proof, see, for example, Samko's book *Hypersingular Integrals and Their Applications*), and so the integral of $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f$ need not be zero.

---

A nice explicit example is $$f(x) = (1 + |x|^2)^{\alpha/2 - n/2},$$ which corresponds to $$g(x) = c_{n,\alpha} (1 + |x|^2)^{-\alpha/2 - n/2}.$$ This follows, for example, from Corollary 1 [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00365-016-9336-4).

Comment: You may find this question interesting: https://mathoverflow.net/q/299770/121665